# How to remove a date from wordpress post

Tags: posts, themes, date

djeddiedavid.info

this is my website i want to remove a date that show on wordpress posts anyone help me ?

[image]

date that show on the bottom of DJ upcoming event

Comment: This is going to be related to a plugin or a theme. Really getting the solution right would require seeing that code.

Comment: this is for theme , no custom development i use purchase theme i want hide its date

Comment: And.... a solution depends on the theme code. Without having that, it is only guessing.

Comment: i can give you link of theme you do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
.latest-post h4 + p {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: thats work dear

Comment: Good :) Be advised that the code hides any <p> tags that immediately follows an <h4> tag while inside a container with the class .latest-post. You would only encounter issues if you add another <h4> tag in the .latest-post container or add another <p> tag above the date.

Comment: ok i will do this

Answer (score 0):

Based of the theme Twenty Fifteen and other popular ones, simply adding `.entry-date { display: none; }` to your stylesheet should hide the date.

Comment: no its not work

Comment: You need to find out the CSS class your date is using then. Try either searching your stylesheet or use the inspector in your browser to find it. another common class for displaying the date and author details is `postmeta` or `post-meta`

Comment: i search in inspect but date has no class and i also dont know where date code is exist

Answer (score 0):

You can try a filter on `get_the_date` but it is likely there will be some formatting/markup left behind:

```
add_filter( 'get_the_date', '__return_empty_string' );
```

Using the Core function [`_return_empty_string()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_return_empty_string) as a callback

Answer (score 0):

Go to your index.php or whatever file is used for latest post.
Find the `<h4>.....</h4>`
Just after this is

```
<p>...the code that adds the date and comments...<p>
<p>...post content...</p>
```

delete or edit the

...the code that adds the date and comments...

Comment: but this will also remove post content

Comment: Edited my answer. It is better to do it in the page code instead of .css